# Python: Waiting on asyncio task to complete that will be ran at some arbitrary point in the future

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This question is best left as a small pseudo example:

```py
async_queue = asyncio.queue
 
class SomeObject:
  async def some_coroutine(self):
    # does things...
 
def main():
  instance = SomeObject()
  async_queue.put(instance)

  # In some other code, the `instance` will be get() from the queue
  # and it's `some_coroutine` will be ran

  # WAIT HERE NOW UNTIL `some_coroutine` in `instance` 
  # has completed... How do I do this?
```

As you can see, `some_coroutine` will be ran at some arbitrary point in the future and I want to wait for that coroutine to actually be ran and finished right after the point where I enqueued it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out about 15 minutes later. Something like this works:

```py
import asyncio
 
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.completed = loop.create_future()
        
    async def some_coroutine(self):
        print('Processing things...')
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        
        self.completed.set_result(True)
        
async def main():
    instance = SomeObject()
    
    # enqueue instance and pretend it's get()
    # in some other code after 5 secs.
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await instance.some_coroutine()
    
    await instance.completed
    print("some_coroutine has finished")
    
asyncio.run(main())
```